# Can't start phpMyAdmin. Keep getting the #2002 socket error

Tags: mysql, macos, sockets, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to set mysql and phpMyAdmin for the last 12 hours, without any success. And yes, after hours and hours of Google-ing I know that is a common problem and I've read similar queries on stackoverflow but still can't come with the solution.....

I've tried everything - from changing the

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']
```

in the `config.inc.php` file to `3306`, `127.0.0.1`....

typing the socket path in the `config.inc.php` file - both  `tmp/mysql.php` and the `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.

I've tried changing the socket path in the my.cnf file and the php.ini....but I keep getting the same error:

```
#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I'm using MySQL (5.1.65), PhpMyAdmin (3.5.2.2) and PHP (5.3.8).

Comment: post your `config.inc.php` code..

Comment: Double check whether mysql is started or not.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi

Comment: Restart MySQL. OSx : `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart` , Linux: `sudo service mysql start` (Old v: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`)

Answer (score 16):

I have recently encountered this problem on Mac OS Sierra too. Apache server is working but mysql is not. After searching for a solution, reading lots of posts I found this solution. And it worked!

The solution is to navigate to the mysql folder, in my case its,

`/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/`

and remove all the files except folders. Then restart MAMP again.

Comment: This worked for me when `killall -9 mysqld` didn't.  I recall it happening after a system crash where nothing terminated cleanly.

Comment: I actually only had to `rm ib_logfile*` (in mysql directory; I also moved to a backup sub-folder instead of hard rm).  I found databases were somehow corrupt  if I had deleted `ibdata1` - mysqld started up and in phpMyAdmin I could see all tables listed in left panel, but not in main panel and could not access any tables either.  Things returned to normal when `ibdata1` was restored and mysqld restarted once again.

Answer (score 13):

1. Quit MAMP
2. Open the terminal
3. Type: killall -9 mysqld Restart MAMP

Comment: There are multiple reasons and solutions this would occur. @axelbrz I am glad could help.

Comment: This also worked for me. Could we get explanations as to the kinds of reasons this would work @andrewoodleyjr ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem I had with this was because PHP was trying to connect via a UNIX socket instead of TCP.  This is similar to this error: [Error when connecting to MySQL using PHP/PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819592/error-when-connecting-to-mysql-using-php-pdo/1819767#1819767)

First, make sure you have a my.cnf config for mysql then add your default socket location:

```
[mysqld_safe] socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Next in your php.ini, let PHP know where it is:

```
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Be sure that you edit php.ini and not php.ini.default.

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not mention MAMP, I am assuming you are not using it so this is for a manual install but it will likely also work for MAMP.

In my experience, this is caused by the socket variable of your mysql. By default, MySQL uses /tmp/mysql.sock.

You can get the MySQL socket variable by logging into your MySQL and doing

```
show variables like '%socket%'
```

that will show you the location of the socket file.

Now, create a php phpinfo() file and look for mysql.default_socket under the mysql or mysqli section. Mine was /var/mysql/mysql.sock. This shows that PHP is looking for the file in a different location than mysql is using.

Assuming you have same values, open new terminal and enter

```
cd /var
mkdir mysql
cd mysql
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

this will create a link to the mysql socket file inside the location PHP is checking from.

PHPMyAdmin should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Check the config file:

```
/* $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
```

Restart MySQL:
OSx : `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`

Linux: `sudo service mysql start` 
(Old linux: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on Windows 7 Ultimate, AppServ.
Just reload SQL and Apache (but you need to reload both of them, reloading only Apache didn't worked).

```
PHPMyAdmin 4.6.6
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30
Server version: 5.7.17-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
PHP: 5.6.30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using homebrew restart mariadb. I also had the same issue and after stopping and starting mariadb it started working again.

`brew services restart mariadb`

Answer (score 0):

Am using MAMP on a macbook pro running High Sierra, and
in my case, I tried all the above but it still did not work for me so I did the following :

1. Looking for where you installed your MAMP and more specifically, look for the  "config.inc.php" file located in "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin".

[image]

2. Backup (ie. on a mac, right click and duplicate) the "config.inc.php" file before we touch it. You can call or rename it "config_old.inc.php"
3. Open the file in your favorite IDE or text editor.

[image]

4. Look for the following lines ;

i) $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']

ii) $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']

iii) $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']

Change from :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Change from :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
```

/*this might be your default. Just check to see from your MAMP installation preference , press CMD + , and confirm that port number you have specified. In my case I had changed it to 8889.*/

[image]

to :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '8889';
```

Again depending on where you installed your MAMP or to be more specific your mysql.

Change from :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = 'some_folder_path or EMPTY';
```

to :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql/mysql.sock';
```

After this modification, save and refresh in your web browser.

Worked for me. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

check that `mysql-server` already installed if not
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: `-1` because `apt-get` routine is for debian systems; this question was assigned a `macos` tag. It is also clearly stated in the question the version of MySQL being used.