# "Connection Refused" or "No Such File or Directory"

Tags: php, mysql, server, dreamhost

I have a [website](http://www.aashishbharadwaj.com) hosted by DreamHost. The subdomain "fakestore" has a database, and consequently a script to access that database. However, I am unable to get that database to work. I've tried changing `$servername` to `127.0.0.1`, and to `aashishbharadwaj.com`. If I use localhost, I get the error `It no work!SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`. If I use the other two I get `It no work!SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

```
<?php
    $servername = 'localhost';   //I've tried numerous things here, with different errors

    //For my server
    $username = "username";   //Not actual username
    $password = "password";   //Not actual password

    $dbname = 'database_name';   //Not actual database name

    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo "It no work!";
        echo $error_message;
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's on DreamHost

Comment: I spent about 4 hours googling and attempting troubleshooting. Please do not make assumptions.

Comment: Seems to me "It **does not** work!" would be much more correct

Comment: @kay27 That was in there as a joke...

Comment: @Nic3500 Please read the post, I did post what I tried, how it failed, and its error. Specifically, I tried two other host names, one providing a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you check the hostname created when creating the database, according to https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215733647-What-PHP-commands-do-I-use-to-connect-to-my-database-

If you want to use `localhost` - please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1819767/5920627